# How to save activity state after navigating?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, savestate

I have an app with 3 activities,`home`,`calculationResult` and `help`.What I'm trying to do is save the details of the calculations on `calculationResult` when the user navigates to `help`.So when the user is in `help` and presses the action bar back icon,the results of the calculation will still be there in `calculationResult`.

I have tried to implement this so far by following this guide: [Recreating an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html),But when I implemented it the variable I'm wanting to store is not recognized when using with `savedInstanceState`.Below is how I have tried to do this in the result class.Can someone point out where I have gone wrong with this or if this is the correct way to accomplish saving the activity state?

```
public class CalcResult extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView result1;

static final String MARK1 = "marking1";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) { 
            // Restore value of members from saved state 
            //not recognizing this variable mark1 which I'm setting to the variable that stores the result of the calculation.
            mark1 = savedInstanceState.getDouble(MARK1); 
        }

        final Intent intent1=new Intent(this,AboutActivity.class);
        final Intent intent2=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final Intent intent3=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.a,
                null);

        // Set up your ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        final Button actionBarHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        actionBarHome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent2);

            }

        });

        final Button actionBarInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_staff);
        actionBarInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_help);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent1);

            }

        });


        final Button actionBarHoome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_home);
        actionBarHoome.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appicon);
        actionBarHoome.setOnClickListener(this);
        actionBarHoome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                

               startActivity(intent3);

            }

        });
        result1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.markOne);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        double markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        result1.setText(String.valueOf(df.format(markOne)+"mm"));

    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        //Also doesn't recognise markOne here ->
        savedInstanceState.putDouble(MARK1, this.markOne);


        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: markOne is not a member of the class but only of the function "onCreate", so it is not visible in any other function. And you have to override "onRestoreInstanceState" as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
double markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
```

You should write

```
markOne = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
```

by declaring it again you are not assigning the value to the class level `markOne`

Also you can try setting the lauchmode of your calculateResult activity as singleTop

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This will use the same instance of the activity that already exist on the top of the stack so will have the same state as before.

Try calling finish in your `Help` activity when you move to `CalculationResult` activity.

for ex:

```
StartActivity(<Intent>);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I tried setting the launchMode to `singleTop` but that didn't fix it.Would you have any idea how to save it,I was thinking of saving the variable to the memory,would you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try calling finish in your `Help` activity when you move to `CalculationResult` activity.

Comment: so, android:launchMode:finish in the help activity? Or is it a different syntax?

Comment: Inside help activity when you start calculationResult activity just call finish().

Answer (score 0):

onRestoreInstanceState() is called when **Activity was killed by the OS**. "Such situation happen when: 
•orientation of the device changes (your activity is destroyed and recreated)
 •there is another activity in front of yours and **at some point the OS kills your activity in order to free memory**.

Next time when you start your activity onRestoreInstanceState() will be called."

But in your case, this might not happen.

Comment: Can you show me a code example with my class,it would be easier to understand like this than theory.thanks

Comment: How about a more simple way of storing the value in a Shared Preferences and displaying the data. Default, you can store a value as "NOVALUE ENTERED" and if the value is modified, you can update the TextView based on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach i followed**

I set a global varibale to act as a flag if i am launching this activity for the first time. If the global varibale is the same as what i had set, i leave the editText untouched. (in your case, result1). If the value is changed, i set the editText for this value. If the user clicks the editText even once, i track the change and store the value. When you think, the mark1 is no longer needed, you can set the value of flag again as "FIRSTENTRY". This would work.

Kindly try and let us know if you still face issues.

**Step 1**

Created a class to store a static Global variable.

```
public class Constants {        
public static String sFlag= "FIRSTENTRY";
}
```

**Step 2**

Add this piece of code after "setContentView(R.layout.result);" line in your oncreate method. **Instead of TextView, i have declared result1 as EditText.**

```
if(!Constants.sFlag.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTENTRY"))
        {
            result1.setText(Constants.sFlag);
        }

        result1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Constants.sFlag = result1.getText().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                Constants.sFlag = result1.getText().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Constants.sFlag = result1.getText().toString();
            } 

        });
```